# tdLib (tdjson_export.h) нет файла

Tags: golang, telegram

хочу подключить свой аккаунт, но вот api подводит делаю все как в инструкции, но при запуске сервера на golang пишет что tdjson_export.h не найден, и его и вправду там нет, даже на репозитории, не знаю что делать

Comment: https://github.com/tdlib/td/issues/257?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать сервис https://www.t-a-a-s.ru/ - с ним вам не нужно устанавливать и компилировать TDLib, вы можете сразу же начать работу используя API не заботясь о самой библиотеке.